# Subspace iteration for finding lowest eigen values for generalized eigen value

Tags: matlab, matrix, eigenvalue

I have a question regarding subspace iteration method for the generalized eigenvalue problem.
I am using MATLAB to solve for a few of the lowest eigenvalues using the subspace iteration method.
After solving the reduced system, do we normalize eigenvectors with respect to mass matrix?

For example:

```
[eve,eva] = eig(full(kred),full(mred));
x = xbar*eve % update eigen vector
```

Before the `x` update, should we perform

```
nn = eve'*mred*eve 
for i = 1:min(2*m,m+8)
    evec(:,i) = evec(:,i)/sqrt(i,i);
end
```

and then update `x`? When I use the subspace method without `nn` and the for-loop, the lowest eigenvalues are
not the same when compared to the lowest of the complete eigenvalues (from matlab `eig`). When I use the
`nn` and the for-loop, I see the eigenvalues are the same.  **The algorithm does not include these additional steps,
but without these, the results from matlab did not match my iterative method.** Is there any particular reason
behind this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Thanks macduff for editing and providing tags to my question.